# Is it safe to touch electrical hot wire while wearing high resistance boots?

Tags: resistance

I never do this and it seems dangerous, but I want to know **is it safe to touch electrical hot wire (with bare finger) in your home electrical outlet, while standing in the land and using high electical resistance boots/shoe?**

Is it safe in theory? Is it safe in practice?

Note: *Assume that the boots has very high elecrical resistance that could resist your home voltage.*

Comment: Lets suppose no current can pass through your legs. If you touch something with your other hand or any other part of your body, you can still get electrocuted.

Comment: Are you trying to repair something? Just turn off the breaker.

Comment: No, its not, it turns you into a capacitor and you conduct electricity. I've done it, it doesn't feel good.

Comment: @laptop2d I don't understand, If we put the resistance in the ground (ex: wearing boots) we get electrocuted, but if we put the resistance in the hot wire (ex: using electrical screw test) we get electrocuted too, but with very less current. Why is that? Is it because the current travel from hot wire to the ground, but not otherwise?

Comment: I don't know directly, but I can say for sure that you can still get shocked from an electric fence while wearing rubber boots.

Comment: @ZynskavZynskav Current doesn't only travel through resistors it also travels through capacitors. If you grab hot wire, you turn yourself into an antenna. Last time I checked radio waves traveled through the air, you make a poor 60Hz (or 50Hz) antenna, but with 120V+ volts a small amount of capacitance goes a long way.

Comment: @laptop2d what are you wearing when you say this " I've done it, it doesn't feel good." ?

Comment: @ZynskavZynskav I was electrically isolated from any conductors

Comment: @laptop2d So the current from hot wire could travel to your body as a "capacitor", without the ground/return path? That's amazing ! I can't believe

Comment: @ZynskavZynskav I'm shocked that you haven't heard of radio.

Comment: @laptop2d Does current flow in the radio antenna?

Answer (score 3):

In theory it's safe,  workers do repairs on live 110,000 volt lines, and are safe because they do not touch ground, or the adjacent conductors,

In practice you need to be sure not to complete the electrical curcuit with any other part of your body (not just your feet) and not to be bumped or distracted by other people or things.

Suppose the screw for the live terminal falls into your boot.  you have to take it out of your boot, place it back into the screw hole and tighten it without touching the earthed metalwork or the earth or neurtral conductors.
or letting the loose live wire short out against anything else.

Suppose it falls on the ground... you can't touch the ground, or before you do, you need to secure the live circuit so that you don't need to hold it

If your're working on a live domestic circuit and for some reason cannot turn it off, don't touch it with your hands, use insulated tools that are designed for working with live circuits. (not just pliers with rubber grips, pliers with 1000V written on the rubber grips)
[image: 1000V pliers]

Comment: If you accidentally short the hot to the grounded box the molten metal from the arc could blind you, following which the breaker will blow, plunging the room into darkness, you lose your grip on the ladder and go tumbling to the floor and down the stairs to end up with a fractured skull, broken limbs and damaged eyes. But not "electrocuted" (in either sense of the word).

Comment: Of course it is safe when not touching the ground. Of course it is safe when touching hot wire with rubber grip. But i want to know: is it safe to touch electrical hot wire (with bare finger) in your home electrical outlet, while standing in the land and using high electical resistance boots/shoe?

Is it safe in theory? Is it safe in practice?

Comment: @ZynskavZynskav If you have to ask it is not safe.

Comment: safe in theory, if your boots have a safety test certificate.  to touch only safe in practice if not crowded, to do any work, not safe.

Comment: If we put the resistance in the ground (ex: wearing boots) we get electrocuted, but if we put the resistance in the hot wire (ex: using electrical screw test) we get electrocuted too, but with very less current. Why is that? Is it because the current travel from hot wire to the ground, but not otherwise?

Comment: your boots are not the good insulator you thought they were.

Comment: @Jasen I think it has more to do with your body acting as a capacitor.

Comment: still safe, even if not comfortable. if you body capacitance is 100pF that's like 2 microamperes RMS (250V@50hz)

Comment: Aren't VDE tools plastic coated, rather than rubber?  Some datasheets say they self extinguish which suggests uPVC. Not sure if anything is made of true rubber these days apart from kid's balloons.

Comment: Adult baloons too. elastic bands, paint...

Answer (score 1):

Rubber-soled shoes do indeed provide some electrical insulation to help protect someone from conducting shock current through their feet.

However, most common shoe designs are not intended to be electrically “safe,” their soles being too thin and not of the right substance.

Also, any moisture, dirt, or conductive salts from body sweat on the surface of or permeated through the soles of shoes will compromise what little insulating value the shoe had to begin with.

**There are shoes specifically made for dangerous electrical work, as well as thick rubber mats made to stand on while working on live circuits, but these special pieces of gear must be in absolutely clean, dry condition in order to be effective.**  Suffice it to say, normal footwear is not enough to guarantee protection against electric shock from a power system.

Research conducted on contact resistance between parts of the human body and points of contact (such as the ground) shows a wide range of figures (see end of chapter for information on the source of this data):

Hand or foot contact, insulated with rubber: 20 MΩ typical. 
Foot contact through leather shoe sole (dry): 100 kΩ to 500 kΩ. 
Foot contact through leather shoe sole (wet): 5 kΩ to 20 kΩ.

As you can see, not only is rubber a far better insulating material than leather, but the presence of water in a porous substance such as leather greatly reduces electrical resistance.

source: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-3/shock-current-path/

Comment: Based on this data, it does not matter where you put the resistance, as long as it EFFECTIVE, it is safe to touch hot wire with bare finger, but again, it is really not recommended.

Comment: Laptop2d gave you comnents about capacitive coupling. You are still talking about DC resistance. But 120V or 230V ic AC. And it can flow through a capacitor. Your body is a big capacitor, so small current will flow through your body even you are wearing clean boots.

Comment: @Chupacabras DC or AC it's the same principle, DC can flow through a capacitor too. Yes a small current will flow, because the circuit is complete, like when you are using "electrical screw test".

Comment: No, DC cannot flow through ideal capacitor. Non-ideal capacitor usually have parasitic parallel resistance, and DC can flow through this resistance. But this is different topic.

Comment: @ZynskavZynskav Sure but that current is only momentary. As soon as the capacitor charges up, no more (significant) current flows. Contrast that with AC where current can flow continuously through the capacitor.

Comment: @Chupacabras So an AC current could flow from hot wire only to the capacitor? Without completing the circuit?

Answer (score 1):

From [popular mechanics 1923](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=LtoDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA632&dq=popular+mechanics+nails+in+shoes+kill+electric+worker&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ1IfYoOXWAhUNLVAKHRZKDg0Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)
[image]

Perhaps your shoes don't have any nails in them.

Comment: I'm sure they don't put any nails, in those shoes "specifically made for dangerous electrical work".

Comment: Ever stood on a drawing pin?